# Is it possible (probably with javascript) to change the HTML page content without loading a different HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

So I have just recently started with web design.
My index.html has a menu (consisting of  containing links to different pages).
The menu on the index.html page (in a very simplified way, no css and things like that) looks something like this:

```
<ul>
<li><a class="active" href="index.html"></li>
<li><a href="contactus.html"></li>
<li><a href="help.html"></li>
<ul>
and then there is the content of the page (text, slideshow, images...) - say 
<div>
<h1><img><p><script>  
</div>
```

the contactus.html page looks somethinglike this:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html"></li>
<li><a class="active" href="contactus.html"></li>
<li><a href="help.html"></li>
<ul>
and then there is the content of the page (text, slideshow, images...) - say 
<div>
<h1><img2><p><script>
```

When you click on the link, it leads you to a different page.
So say we have index.html, we click on a link in the menu and it leads us to contactus.html. It changes the page, the contactus.html has to load.
And the question is: is it possible to make it so that the content of contactus.html appears on index.html (and replaces it) but in such a way that does not require another page loading?
I have done some research and found something about innerHTML, but I cannot really understand how to use it. I started with js not a long time ago.
I hope the question somehow makes sense.
Thanks a lot for your suggestions and advice.

Comment: Yes it is possible

Comment: and how if i may ask?

Comment: Done that way (replacing the entire content of index with another page) wont give you any advantage, you are effectively loading another page. What you probably want is to load single fragments of content and update the current page, this can be done in a lot of ways...  from using jQuery for simple ajax and dom manipulation to full flagged Single Page Applications with Sveltejs, Angular, Vuejs, React and other frameworks.

Comment: The easiest method is with ajax, but that requires some php knowledge.

Comment: So what do you personally find the easiest? I just need to change an article, slideshow and the menu active class

Comment: And if I use javascript? I am not sure, but something with innerHTML? Or DOM

Comment: Yes it is possible, but that's not really efficient. ReactJs, Angular, VueJs and stuff like that can help you do that efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah. `document.body.innerHTML = "<p>Some new HTML!</p>"`. And there are lots of other ways as well. I like React, but it definitely has a learning curve. I don't know if real web developers still use jQuery, but it makes a lot of DOM manipulation stuff pretty easy. Good luck!

Comment: thank you very much! and how would I implement this into the code please?

Comment: Again, lot's of possibilities, but maybe easiest would be, change your contactus link to `<a onclick="contactus()">` and then have a javascript function: `function contactus() { document.body.innerHTML = ...}` The need to escape quote marks may get gnarly, which is part of why I like React. Anyway, I'm not saying this is a *good* way to do what you're asking, but it should be easy for you, and it will change the content instantly.

Comment: No, we real developers add a pointless 50% of our search queries to append `-jquery`. It's a frigin disaster and is as hated as WordPress. Also *never* use `innerHTML` as it's not standard and it's buggy as hell but only after you have a large amount of clients depending on you and suddenly you realize that you have a thousand instances of it in your code and 90% of the data you thought was solid is found to be corrupt.

Answer (score 0):

What server do you use? Do you use apache or ngnix for the html files?
You can get the content of "Contacts.html" and replace the content's html with it.

For example:

```
$.get("contacts.html", function(data, status){
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = data;
});
```

This code uses jQuery for ajax requests and you can use XMLHttpRequest with only javascript.
Caution: You shouldn't run the html only. This will not work without html server.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This will be an extremely simplistic answer because it is a huge argument... but lets start with some basics.

The objective is, starting from a web page (index.html), to load some content and update only part of the content in the current page.

I will suggest two different approaches for both client and server side of the equation.

**jQuery + HTML fragments**

The idea of this approach is to use jQuery to manage AJAX requests to retrieve some content from the server and to update the DOM of the current page to display the new content.

**Server side**

Here you need to expose some content, in the simplest of cases it can be just a fragment of html like this:

*fragment.html*

```html
<p>My asynchronously loaded content!<p>
```

The fragment above can be exposed directly as static content through apache or nginx, or can be generated dynamically with PHP, Java, C# or any programming language with good support for web development.

**Client side**

On the client we want to contact the server from javascript and retrieve the content with an AJAX request, then update the html. jQuery enables us to do both of those things.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test page</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Home page</h1>

        <div id="content">
            <p>Welcome!</p>
        </div>

        <div>
            <button id="update-btn">Update content</button>
        </div>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#update-btn').click(function(){
            $.get('http://myserver/fragment.html').then(function(data) {
                $('#content').html(data);
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

We have a *div* with id *content* which we will use as the target for the new content, and a button with id *update-btn* to launch the request.

In the `<script>` block we first associate the *click* event to the button so that when clicked we send an ajax request to the server using [jQuery get method](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) and update the html content with [jQuery html method](https://api.jquery.com/html/).

**Javascript framework + REST API**

This is definitely a more complex approach and a complete guide/example is out of scope for a SO answer (there are books hundreds of pages long for each client side framework and for each server side language/framework) but let's explore the base concept behind this idea.

In the previous example we had the server generate an html and then the client ask for more html to update itself. Here the basic idea is the same but with a much more clear separation of concerns where the server is in charge of generating and sending raw data to the client (usually in [JSON](https://www.json.org/) or [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) format), and the client has to manage all of the presentation and user interaction aspects.

As an example we can analyze the hacker-news get item api.

The url structure is [https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/{item-id}.json?print=pretty](https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/%7Bitem-id%7D.json?print=pretty)

We can make a GET request with a an id as a path variable and an optional query parameter called *print* and it will return some JSON data.

For example we can `curl https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/25213368.json?print=pretty` and get the following response:

```json
{
  "by" : "harporoeder",
  "descendants" : 8,
  "id" : 25213368,
  "kids" : [ 25224137, 25224226, 25224397 ],
  "score" : 31,
  "time" : 1606333258,
  "title" : "Use `nproc` and not grep /proc/cpuinfo",
  "type" : "story",
  "url" : "https://www.flamingspork.com/blog/2020/11/25/why-you-should-use-nproc-and-not-grep-proc-cpuinfo/"
}
```

Once we have all the services we need exposed the client can be built with many different frameworks and libraries. In the first approach we used jQuery which is fine for very simple use cases but can become a hell to write and maintain when we start adding complexity to our application, this is why there are many different frameworks to implement the client such as: [VueJS](https://vuejs.org/), [React](https://reactjs.org/), [SvelteJS](https://svelte.dev/), [Angular](https://angular.io/), [Aurelia](https://aurelia.io/) and many others.

Each one of those javascript frameworks has a big learning curve and you will most probably also need to learn how to work with Nodejs, NPM, transpilers and bundlers to make use of the whole modern javascript infrastructure.

This will not be an easy journey but you will learn a valuable skill if you decide to go this road.

Hope this gives you an idea on how to go on with learning web development.

Comment: Never *ever* use jQuery, well frameworks and libraries in general but especially jQuery. You'll end up with five versions that aren't compatible with each other, wretched performance and the inability to take on new work because you're stuck in maintenance hell. All the time wasted on learning a framework could have been invested in learning *pure JavaScript* that will *not* expire with some new version in three months. I've built an entire web platform from scratch so I speak from experience. :-)

Comment: Generally speaking yes, i agree, as i said that is the simplistic approach and much better option is to go with a specialized framework. In practice it all depends on the use case, i will probably not build a whole VueJS application to change the color a button in an otherwise static website.

Answer (score -1):

[This](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-star-tf7zg?file=/src/index.js) is your answer with vanilla javascript.

index.js file is:

```
onclick = "changeHtml()";
const button = document.getElementById("btn");
button.addEventListener("click", function () {
  document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `
  <h1>I'm another HTML</h1>
  <div >
  <p>Look at me</p>
  </div>
  `;
});
```

and index.html file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <h1>Hello Vanilla!</h1>
      <div>
        <p>This is initial HTML</p>
        <button id="btn">Click Me!</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can change the content of any tag in HTML. like `<body>`, `<a>`, etc.